# How do I edit a Meteor package from Atmosphere that's not on GitHub?

Tags: node.js, twitter, meteor, oauth, npm

I have some Twitter functionality I'm working on and I want to use "Application-Only Authentication" which only needs my Twitter application credentials to just perform GETS in my app (e.g. random tweet searches based on user inputted tags, etc. - no actual user posting.)

Twitter supports this but most of the Twitter packages on Atmosphere and NPM do not. They force you to pass both application credentials and OAuth tokens, if you don't, your requests come back invalid.  The most popular Meteor Twitter API package called `mrt:twit` actually wraps the NPM package `ttezel/twit` which actually implements Application-Only Authentication correctly, however the wrapper package for Meteor `mrt:twit` forces you to use Full Authentication requiring the user's OAuth tokens which I don't want or need to use.  So I'd like to edit `mrt:twit` to properly follow `ttezel/twit's` interface.

However, the `mrt:twit` package is not on GitHub. How do I figure out where this lives and/or if I can access it locally and modify it and/or find some repository online for where it lives?  Atmosphere doesn't offer much help providing no links from where this package is actually downloading?

Link for `mrt:twit`: https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/twit

Link for `ttezel/twit`: https://github.com/ttezel/twit

**EDIT**:  I'm using Meteor 1.1.0.2. I was able to find where `mrt:twit` is locally.  It's at:

`.../.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/`

After investigating, it's not that `mrt:twit` doesn't "implement" `ttezel/twit's` interface correctly, it's that `mrt:twit` is using/requiring an old version of `ttezel/twit`, version 1.1.9 instead of the current 2.1.0.  That old version of `ttezel/twit` doesn't support the "application-only" authorization - I can see it in the code. Hence my above original issue. `ttezel/twit` downloads to the following folder:

`.../.meteor/local/build/programs/server/npm/mrt_twit/node_modules/twit`

Inside the above folder I see the full .git package for `ttezel/twit` but it's version 1.1.9.  So I assume I could just replace this folder with the latest 2.1.0 version of `ttezel/twit` but I don't think you're supposed to have to mess with anything inside of an `node_modules` folder right? Shouldn't there be a config file somewhere to edit?

For the life of me I can't find where `mrt:twit` is declaring to use version 1.1.9.  In all the code it just calls `Npm.require('twit')`.  There's no config file I can find that sets the version to 1.1.9.  The only thing I found is a file at the second path above sitting next to the `twit` folder called `.node_version` and all it has in it is `v0.10.20` which is a version of Node to use I assume.  That wouldn't "force" whatever package versions were out at that time would it?  If so, then that's probably what is setting `ttezel/twit` to use 1.1.9.

My original post question still exists though, where can I find `mrt:twit` on a server so I can fork it/edit it and not have to edit the code locally?

Comment: did you try looking in $HOME/.meteor/packages?

Comment: I saw that path on various posts but all that leads to is the text file "packages" that lists my packages used.  There's no folder or code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed the creators of Atmosphere ([percolatestudio.com](http://www.percolatestudio.com)) and Tom was really helpful and pointed me to where `mrt:twit` lives on GitHub.  It's on the old 1.0 atmosphere:

https://old-atmosphere.meteor.com/package/twit

And that page points to the actual GitHub location which is:

https://github.com/subhog/meteor-twit

So the above link is from where the current `mrt:twit` package downloads into your Meteor app if you add it to your app (as of this writing).  Once I found that I could easily see in the `package.js` file it declares `Npm.depends({twit: "1.1.9"})`. On a side note: It would be nice if the current version of Atmosphere pointed you to the GitHub location of older/legacy packages how it does the new packages.

So I was able to fork this and update the package to use version 2.1.0 of `ttezel/twit`.  I made a pull request for `mrt:twit` so hopefully the author updates it - as this is the number one Twitter API package for Meteor with 1,200 downloads.  Seemed better to update it than to publish my own version.

Until then, I made a local package following the below link and everything is working great - including application-only authentication.  Thanks for the comments - they were helpful. I'm still pretty new at Meteor and how the packaging system works.

http://www.webtempest.com/meteor-js-packages-tutorial

If you want to access the updated package I made it's at the below link but it's not a published meteor package - so you'll have to download it and use it locally:

https://github.com/evolross/meteor-twit

Answer (score 0):

You should check `.meteor/local/*` folders.

I have a lot of packages files in `.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages`

I'm afraid it's all compiled but you can grab some code you need and make your own package.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I found the files locally and updated my question

Comment: Keep in mind that you can't (should not) make any changes inside .meter folder. Why don't you make you own package? Your issue I guess is not Meteor but Npm. Npm.require just grabs module you have installed. My suggestion would be to make your own package that would wrap twit module with version that you need. There should be some articles in the internet on how to make your own packages that depends on npm module. [http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Npm-depends](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Npm-depends)